# Flexslider pause button

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am trying to get pause working on flexslider. Here is the code I am using.

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    slideshowSpeed: 3000,
    animationDuration: 1100,
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: true,
    pausePlay: true,
    pauseText: 'Pause',
    playText: 'Play', 

});
});
```

It only displays the element and text for pause, but doesn't affect anything. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

Looking at the flexslider code I think this must be the section which handles the button. The actual code is a bit over my head but I can't see anything that looks like a click event handler.

```
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //FlexSlider: Pause/Play
  if (slider.vars.pausePlay) {
    var pausePlayScaffold = $('<div class="flex-pauseplay"><span></span></div>');

    if (slider.containerExists) {
      slider.controlsContainer.append(pausePlayScaffold);
      slider.pausePlay = $('.flex-pauseplay span', slider.controlsContainer);
    } else {
      slider.append(pausePlayScaffold);
      slider.pausePlay = $('.flex-pauseplay span', slider);
    }

    var pausePlayState = (slider.vars.slideshow) ? 'pause' : 'play';
    slider.pausePlay.addClass(pausePlayState).text((pausePlayState == 'pause') ? slider.vars.pauseText : slider.vars.playText);

    slider.pausePlay.bind(slider.eventType, function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if ($(this).hasClass('pause')) {
        slider.pause();
        slider.manualPause = true;
      } else {
        slider.resume();
        slider.manualPause = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: do you have an URL where you are implementing this?

Comment: I found the problem. For some reason my flex-control-nav list was preventing the click event, it must have been covering the flex-pauseplay div. I think I will put this in an answer and accept it for anyone in a similar situation as it's common enough to move these control elements around.

Comment: funny you know i thought about that but then i didnt say it - that's why i asked for a live site... next time i'm going to speak my mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the problem was with my CSS. I had moved the **flex-control-nav** ordered list and it seems to have been preventing the click event, it must have been covering the **flex-pauseplay** div.